# Angular JS Directive - Template, compile or link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create an Angular JS directive to check the length of a string, if it is too long to shorten it using a Filter, and show an Angular-UI popover on mouseover.

Where in the directive should I be placing the functionality to get this to work (link, template or compile)?

The view:

```
<div myapp-shorten="project">{{project.Description}}</div>
```

Here are my first attempts at the directive so far:

```
angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
 .directive('myappShorten', function () {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var outputText = "";

        if (myappShorten.Description.length > 20) {
            outputText += "<div popover='{{myappShorten.Description}}' popover-trigger='mouseenter'>" +
            "{{myappShorten.Description | cut:true:20:' ...'}}</div>";
        } else {
            outputText += "<div>{{myappShorten.Description}}</div>";
        }

        element.text(outputText);
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        scope: {
            myappShorten: "="
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Perhaps a more comprehensive overview of directive functions: [Angular directives - when to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you can change the filter that it wouldn't alter string if it doesn't need to

Second, since you only need filter and popover - template is enough.

```
 angular.module('myapp.directives', [])
   .directive('myappShorten', function () {

     return { 
       scope: { data : '=myappShorten',
       template:"<div popover='{{data.Description}}' popover-trigger='mouseenter'>" +
        "{{ data.Description | cut:true:20:' ...' }}</div>"
     }
   })
```

Alternatively you can use combination of `ng-show` and `ng-hide`

```
 app.directive('shorten', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A'
    , scope :  {
        shorten : '=',
        thestring: '='   
    }
    , template: "<div ng-show='sCtrl.isLong()' tooltip='{{ sCtrl.str }}'>{{ sCtrl.short() }}</div>"+
                "<div ng-hide='sCtrl.isLong()'>{{ sCtrl.str }}</div>"

    , controllerAs: 'sCtrl'
    , controller: function ($scope) {
        this.str = $scope.shorten || ''
        this.length = $scope.thestring || 20

        this.isLong = function() {
            return this.str.length > this.length   
        }

        this.short = function() {
            if ( this.str.length > this.length)  {
                return this.str.substring(0,this.length)  + '...'                    
            }
        }                                  
    }                               
  }       
})
```

Third option would be to actually use compile and $watch on myappShrten.Description but it seems to be overkill to me.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, the 2nd one is perfect for me. I would also like to pass in the length property into this directive but am having newbie problems here. This is my view: `<shorten thestring="project.Description" thelength="30"></shorten>`. How can I access these properties in the example above?

Comment: I just had to change `restrict: 'A'` to `restrict: 'E'` and check the variable names and this works perfectly. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the value of `thestring` to be able to change so I had to move the code from the `controller` into the `link` function as you can see from the alternative answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The above accepted answer works fine. But if the value of `thestring` changes this will not update as the controller compiles on first run and then will not update if the value changes. Putting code into the `controller` compiles upfront, but putting the code in the `link` function allows it to update if the value changes. This is my preferred solution inspired by the solution above:

**The view:**

```
<shorten thestring="project.Description" thelength="40"></shorten>
```

**The directive:**

```
.directive('shorten', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        , scope: {
            thelength: '=',
            thestring: '='
        }
        , link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.isLong = function () {
                return scope.thestring.length > scope.thelength
            }

            scope.short = function () {
                if (scope.thestring.length > scope.thelength) {
                    return scope.thestring.substring(0, scope.thelength) + '...'
                }
            }

        }

        , template: "<div class='handCursor' ng-show='isLong()' tooltip='{{ thestring }}'>{{ short() }}</div>" +
                    "<div ng-hide='isLong()'>{{ thestring }}</div>"
    }
});
```